# Erlang HTTP(S) proxy example

Tags: https, proxy, erlang, http-proxy

I'm trying to learn Erlang, and would like to get a feel by investigating some small real life project.

Can you please give a link to the open source HTTP(S) proxy in Erlang?

Ideally it should have short code and be in a working state.

I believe HTTP(S) proxy is a good example because it highlights some features of the Erlang I'm interested: parallel, networking, binary streaming, should handle failures and timeouts etc.

Also, I have experience with HTTP(S) proxy in node.js and it would be interesting to compare the code and its complexity.

Comment: something like this: https://github.com/afiskon/erlang-http-proxy ?

Comment: Thanks, but it seems like it's partially finished, it says "it's supported only GET, POST и HEAD". I'd like to see complete example if possible. Also it doesn't support keep-alive.

Comment: I need fully working example to access the complexity, how it looks compared to Node.js or Go

Comment: then maybe this: https://github.com/Wavenet/http_proxy

Comment: Thanks, will check it out.

Comment: https://github.com/heroku/vegur